# How to remap Alt-TAB app-switching for Ubuntu-guest/OSX-host VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, application-switcher

I just setup an Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS Virtualbox (guest) in an OSX Lion host.

It's mostly fine, but one annoyance is that, to switch between apps in the Ubuntu guest's interface, I need to press ⌥-TAB (aka Option Key-TAB), whereas my brain/finger wiring calls for pressing ⌘-TAB (aka Command Key-TAB).  To be more specific, it calls for pressing *Left*-⌘-TAB.  (Left-⌘ = the ⌘ key to the *left* of the space bar.)

> Is there a way to re-map the Ubuntu guest's app-switching action to Left-⌘-TAB?

(FWIW, currently I have the VirtualBox's host key mapped to *Right*-⌘, but I'd be happy to change this setting if it conflicts with the solution to the problem above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open *System Settings/Keyboard*, there select the *Shortcuts* Tab. Now select *Navigation* and scroll down till you find *Switch Applications*. There you can select another shortcut just by typing it.

[image]